# Setting initially focused tab in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I have two pinned tabs in Chrome, in addition to my "home" screen which appears in a third, non-pinned tab. In Chrome 76, when I opened the browser for the first time each day, my "home" tab was initially given focus.

In Chrome 77, however, that has changed. Now the left-most tab appears to be the one that gets focus initially. Is there a way I can modify this behavior, either through an extension or some other hidden setting? I'd like the browser to start with my "home" tab focused by default.